# How to create a page from an example page replacing certain text with user input?

Tags: php, html

I want to make a page, where there's a form

```
    <form class="col s12" method="POST" action="addtask.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Username" id="user" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="user">Username</label>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input placeholder="SkyMaker" id="title" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
       <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input placeholder="This makes a sky" id="desc" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="desc">Description</label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="dlink" placeholder="http://example.com" type="url" class="validate">
      <label for="dlink">Download LInk</label>
    </div>
  </div>
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"         name="action">submit
<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
```

```
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Addtask.php contains:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET["type"]) && isset($_GET["message"]) &&        isset($_GET["line"]) && isset($_GET["file"])) {
if(is_numeric($_GET["line"])) {
    if($_GET["type"] !== "" && $_GET["message"] !== "" && $_GET["file"] !=="") {
        $id = 0;
        while(file_exists($id . ".html")) {
            $id++;
        }
        $html = file_get_contents("example.html");
        $html = str_ireplace("resc_title", $_GET["title"], $html);
        $html = str_ireplace("resc_user", $_GET["user"], $html);
        $html = str_ireplace("resc_desc", $_GET["desc"], $html);
        $html = str_ireplace("resc_dlink", $_GET["dlink"], $html);
        file_put_contents($id . ".html", $html);
        echo "http://example.com" . $id . ".html";
    }
}
```

But, when I submit the form it takes me to a blank page (addtask.php). example.html contains a template, with resc_title, resc_user and all the other ones in certain places, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs all miss the name attribute, so PHP doesnt know about your form fields, you also can combine the str_ireplace into one using array for search and replace keywords

Comment: I added the name to all the inputs. It's still showing a blank page. `<input placeholder="SkyMaker" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="validate">`

Comment: I have an error log, nothing from that file is in it.

Comment: Are sure your condition for the if become true? Where do you set type, message and file?

Comment: Not exactly sure, my friend helped me with this.

Comment: Ok, then just try the folloing add this **before** the if: `var_dump(isset($_GET["type"]) && isset($_GET["message"]) &&        isset($_GET["line"]) && isset($_GET["file"]));` And tell me if the result is true or false

Comment: Do you solved your problem? Or are there any other things that wont work, if it is so feel free to ask me ;)

Comment: Fixed. :) Thank you.